# how to stop specific exceptions from being logged onto the server

Tags: java

I am new to JBoss. As part of My Application I am using JBoss.We are also using EJB's as a part of the project also. A exception like StaleObjectStateException is raised . So , the EJB uses this exception to rollback a transaction. So, Please tell me how to stop StaleObjectStateException from being logged.Log4j is used here.

Comment: first step should be to catch the exception in code itself.

Answer (score 0):

`StaleObjectStateException` being a `runtime` exception, shouldn't be caught in normal cases
But the only way for you to stop it from coming to logs, is to catch the exception in your code and eat up.

However, IMHO it should be of prime importance to figure out why you are getting this exception.

Comment: This StaleObjectStateException is occuring because multiple threads are trying to update an object so this is occuring.This is not a problem.Because it using some kind of checking in database and update the data. But this exception is used by EJB(Predefined) to rollback a transaction.So I just wanted to Remove it from the log.

Answer (score 0):

[org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/StaleObjectStateException.html) is a Hibernate exception that usually indicates that some other thread of control has updated the state of your entity bean in the database.

You must catch it before it is thrown from an EJB and deal with it somehow.

Any RuntimeException that is thrown from an EJB call automatically results in transaction rollback.

You should also read the javadoc for [org.hibernate.StaleStateException](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/StaleStateException.html) to ensure that some of the other scenarios it describes do not apply to you.